# Deleting from UITableView and supporting data source in iOS 4

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4

I'm a bit stumped by this after reading over the Apple documentation and searching The Googles. The gist of the problem is I know I need to delete from the UITableView and the datasource (NSMutableArray in this case) but it won't let me do either regardless of the order I do it in.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {        
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [myMutableObjectList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // not used
    }   
}
```

Regardless of which order I use for these two:

```
     [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
     [myMutableObjectList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

It either complains about how many elements are left or says the deletion did not occur.

> "(Count) before deletion must match (count) after deletion minus however many you've deleted 0 insertions 1 deletion"

With [tableView....] first it says the count is the same with 1 deletion wanting to happen.

With [myMutableObjectList...] first it says count is 1 less (good!) but 0 deletion wanting to happen.

If I can't have it either way, what am I supposed to do?

### Updates:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {   
   if([myMutableObjectList count] == 0) {
      return section; 
   } else {
    return 4; //4 variables in myObject
   }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{   
    NSLog(@"Size of list: %d", [myMutableListList count]);
    if([myMutableList count] == 0) {
        return 100;
    } else {
        return [myMutableList count];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your numberForRowsInSection method?

Comment: Added the method for you in the original post. The NSMutableArray I am using is a list of say 'myObjects' that contain 4 variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numberOfRowsInSection doesn't match the behavior you're going for. It never will reflect changes to your data store.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {   
   if([myMutableObjectList count] == 0) {
      return section; 
   } else {
    return 4; //4 variables in myObject
   }
}
```

Why are you returning section here. I'd imagine you want to return `[myMutableObjectList  count]`

This method needs to reflect the CURRENT count of all the cells. When you do your deletion, you remove an object from `myMutableObjectList` but that change wouldn't affect the result of your numberOfRows method.

Comment: I'm curious! And also a newb at iPhone development obviously! Care to elaborate? Let me guess and say I should be checking the size of the array in the numberOfRowsInSection method? I thought sections were the individual items in the list with the rows being the items in the section?

Comment: Added the other method for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I had answered from my iPhone, which is why it was so short. Fixing with a more proper answer.

Comment: @Joshua Weinberg Appreciate the help! Unfortunately after changing the method I am still getting the error:-- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (73) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (74), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Comment: Take a step back and look at what you're doing. Also read the tableview programming guide. You seem to have some confusion about the difference between rows/sections and how the table updates after removing some of them.

Comment: @Joshua Weinberg - again thanks for your time. After re-reading the tableview programming guide I updated the sections and rows methods so that numberOfSectionsInTableView returns 1 and numberOfRowsInSection returns the count of the list. This fixed my problem. I was over thinking and thus confusing myself about rows and sections as you stated.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out, some of this stuff can be confusing at times.